# Add items side-by-side in a <li>

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to add icons side-by-side in the sabe `<li>` in a dropdown component?

In the example bellow, even using one `<li>` the icons shows in 2 lines. I am hopping to have icons side-by-side with separate links for each icon.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/8u5dpa90/

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span></a>
      <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a tag as `display:inline-block`, check below codes.

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8u5dpa90/2/